# How to get TypeScript's static typings to work on runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
function multiply(num: number): number {
  console.log(num * 10) // NaN
  return num * 10
}

multiply("not-a-number") // result == NaN
```

If i try to call the above function by hard-coding invalid argument type, Typescript will complain. Which is expected.

I was expecting same thing when argument is passed dynamically.

```
const valueFromDifferentSource = "not-a-number"
multiply(valueFromDifferentSource) // result == NaN
```

Instead of breaking the code. Javascript continues to execute the code and returns "Not-a-Number" NaN.

How do i achieve to get typescript's static type work on runtime?

Comment: What kind of construction are you considering when saying `argument is passed dynamically`? Also I tried your code in IntelliJ Enterprise, in an angular-cli project having Typescript 2, and in my case, at design time I get an error `TS2345: Argument of type "not-a-number" is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'`. And at compile time `Argument of type '"not-a-number"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`. So this works for me just fine. Which version of Typescript are you using and how are you compiling the code, also which IDE?

Comment: TypeScript's type checking is compile-time only.

Comment: having an IDE can take advantage of the static typing and check your syntax before compilation-time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `valueFromDifferentSource` has a typing as well:

`const valueFromDifferentSource: number = "not-a-number"`

TypeScript does nothing in run-time. It compiles TypeScript to plain Javascript, and adds nothing in the sense of boiler-plate code which allows run-time checks.

Comment: It's also worth noting that run-time typing is [explicitly a non-goal of the TypeScript project](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals), so it's pretty unlikely anything like that will ever get added in the future.

Comment: no use of doing it. I tried it as well. Imagine you are expecting data from external api which gives "string" response where "number" is required.

Comment: @sravis: If the API does that, your code needs to handle it. TypeScript can't help you there.

Comment: Build your system as tightly as possible, but if you can't make sure it's a certain type, build your code with extra checks to ensure correct behavior. For instance, use a `try` clause, or use something like `if(typeof value !== 'Number') throw 'Error';`

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has nothing to do with runtime. But there is a good library for controlling variable types https://github.com/hapijs/joi. What you usually want to do, is to validate all the input data to your application (http requests, responses from other services, queue messages). Having such validation and static typing internally on a stage of writing a code, should give you what you want and improve code quality as well.